# Starting the script only once the "inventory" has reached a certan compacity in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inventory

I'm writing a game in unity 3d and at one part of the game the player has too pick up the coins to unlock the door.

The inventory script

[inventory script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYcf4.jpg)

I need my button script to know when there is 8 keys so it can unlock

[button script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKmR8.jpg)

Any help would be super great.

Answer (score 0):

You hold a reference to your InventoryScript inside your ButtonScript. Then your ButtonScript can ask your InventoryScript how many keys it has.